# How to show the date variable in the toast message in LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components, toast

Hi how can show the value of the field in the LWC toast message which contains the date.
I am trying to show but getting the value as undefined.

JS code:

```
@track MDate ===2020-07-15
@track StDate === 2019-07-15


showToast(message) {
        const event = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Toast message',
            message: message,
            variant: 'error',
            mode: 'dismissable'
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    
    
this.showToast("Wrong Date selected in the Start Date It Should be between ");
// I want to pass the StDate and MDate as a argument in the message so that it can be displayed as a toast message on UI
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your date to string & append it with your error message -

```
this.showToast("Wrong Date selected in the Start Date It Should be between " + this.MDate.toString() + "-" + this.StDate.toString());
```

Comment: Please note that `toString()` displays the date in full ISO format. Also, you are missing `this` while referring to the date variables. `MDate.toString()` should be  `this.MDate.toString()`